# Rust scoping rules for struct-owned functions

Tags: function, struct, scope, rust

I am trying to understand what exactly the scope is for functions defined within an `impl` block but which don't accept `&self` as a parameter.  For example, why doesn't the following chunk of code compile? I get the error "cannot find function `generate_a_result` in this scope".

```
pub struct Blob {
    num: u32,
}

impl Blob {
    pub fn new() -> Blob {
        generate_a_result()
    }

    fn generate_a_result() -> Blob {
        let result = Blob {
            num: 0
        };

        result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These functions are called ***associated functions***. And they live in the namespace of the type. They always have to be called like `Type::function()`. In your case, that's `Blob::generate_a_result()`. But for referring to your own type, there is the special keyword `Self`. So the best solution is:

```
Self::generate_a_result()
```